# find and prove the necessary and sufficient condition in which (a,b)=[a,b]

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

If we have that $[a,b]=k$ meaning $a|k$ and $b|k$. Is there an equation that we can get from this relation? My problem says "find and prove the sufficient condition in which $(a,b)=[a,b]$". I think it is when $a=b$ but I am trying to prove a biconditional statement that $(a,b)=[a,b]$ if and only if $a=b$. I am stuck in the forward direction.

Any input will help.

Comment: If $a|k$ then it means $k=k_aa$ for some $k_a$, and also $k=k_bb$ for some $k_b$. Also if $(a,b)=n$, then $n|a$ and $n|b$, so $a=n_an$ and $b=n_bn$ for some $n_1,n_b$. Then can you infer something from these decompositions?

Comment: Hint: $(a,b)$ always divides $[a,b]$, and their product is $ab$. Further, $(a,b)  \leq a,b  \leq [a,b]$.

Comment: @AnnaSdTC i got something like that Kakba=Kakbb I assume that gcd(a,b)=lcm(a,b) i am trying to prove a bio conditional statment and this is my forward direction. But yeah where can I get from this equation?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг do you think that would help in that situation ?

Answer (score 2):

The main relation between greatest common divisor and lowest common multiple is
$$
(a,b)[a,b]=ab
$$
(when $a$ and $b$ are positive integers). Suppose $(a,b)=[a,b]$; then
$$
(a,b)^2=ab
$$
On the other hand, $(a,b)\le a$, so $(a,b)^2\le a^2$. In particular
$$
ab\le a^2
$$
so $b\le a$. Similarly, $a\le b$.

Comment: Thank you so much! much simpler and way shorter than my way!

Comment: How do we  go from ab ≤ a2 to the next step?  I am sorry I know it is an algebra thing but I am confused with it

Comment: @HananIbraheim Since $(a,b)=[a,b]$ by assumption, we have $ab=(a,b)[a,b]=(a,b)^2\le a^2$.

Answer (score 1):

See, if $a=b$ then it is obvious that $(a,b)= [a,b]$.

The other way, if $(a,b) = [a,b]$, then because $(a,b) \leq a \leq [a,b]$, it follows that $(a,b) = a$ (because above,equality holds in our case).

Similarly, if $(a,b) = [a,b]$, then because $(a,b) \leq b \leq [a,b]$, it follows that $(a,b) = b$.

Finally, $a = (a,b) = b = [a,b]$ is true.

Therefore, $a = b \iff [a,b] = (a,b)$.

EDIT: If $a=b$, then the "least common multiple" of $a$ and $b$ is obviously $a$ (or $b$). (Because both $a$ and $b$ divide $a$, and $a$ is the smallest number with this property).

Similarly, if $a=b$, the "greatest common divisor" of $a$ and $b$ is obviously $a$ (or $b$).(Because $a$ divides both $a$ and $b$, and $a$ is the largest number with this property).

Hence, $(a,b) = a = [a,b]$, nearly by definition of $\operatorname{lcm}$ and $\gcd$.

Comment: I  thought I can use some algebra to get there. I think your way is perfectly fine , I just need to see if my other way is ok otherwise I will use your hints. Thank you so much . It helped alot

Comment: @HananIbraheim You are welcome!

Comment: that is what I did  , do you think its ok? your way is much simpler tho  I claim that (a,b)=[a,b] if and only if a=b
Let (a,b)=[a,b]=k 
Then k|a and k|b so a=kak ,b=kbk 
[a,b]=k so a|k and b|k so k=aak  and k=bbk
So a=kaaak  we know that a >0 so -ka=ak
 And b=kbbbk  we know that b>0 so -kb=bk
Then a =akk , b =-bkk 
So k =-a/ak , and also k=-b/bk
So abk= bak 
However, bk= k/b and ak= k/a 
So we substitute we get a(k/b)=b(k/a)
So abk=abk 
And ab=ab so a=b=1 thus a=b

Comment: @HananIbraheim That's fine, although it wasn't the easiest to read because of no subscripts. I think you have captured the divisibility idea well in the answer. But how is $a=b=1$ in the end? Also, when you get $k_aa_k = 1$, and transpose, you should get $\frac 1{k_a} = a_k$, not $-k_a = a_k$. But you started correctly.

Comment: yeah I know I am sorry its not easy to read i wish I can upload a word document here. I see , I will go over the algebra again. Thank you so much

Comment: @HananIbraheim You are welcome! (Again, that is to say!)

Comment: when I assume that a=b how do I reason through (a,b)=[a,b]? I know it is obvious but is there a way to explain that?Thanks alot

Comment: I'll edit my answer. Just a minute (and half, maybe).

Comment: Cant thank you enough. Life saving I swear :)

Comment: @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг I actually figured that my way will make it more complicated than it needs to be So if I use your way, I understand when you say a is greater or equal to (a,b) and it is smaller or equal to [a,b] but how do you figure that a=(a,b)?

Comment: @HananIbraheim In the "similarly" statement, I wrote that the  "greatest common divisor" of a and b is obviously a(or b), for the reason given in brackets.